# How can I input data to excel from inputting data in text box where the text box are from two or more Userform Using Excel VB?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to ease the data entry from financial report, so i try to make forms using Excel Visual Basic.

I made 2 Userform so far ,later i will made 5. I made userform so the data entry operator can have simple design of the form, because the textboxs are so many,then I partitioned the sector into 5 userform to simplifiy it.

To move between Sector, the operator can jump to another userform using command button.

When the operator has finished the data entry from all 3 userform, he will comeback to the main Userform to Entry the data all at once into excel.

My problem is, i find it difficult to connect between userform to take the value from each userform so that finally the value can be inputted to excel all at once using 1 command button at the main userform or userform1.

My code for the command button is this:

```
Private Sub cmdAddData_Click()
 'Copy input values to sheet.
Dim lRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Summary")
lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
With ws
    .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.txtNo.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.txtKode.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Me.txtNamaPerusahaan.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.txtSector.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = Me.txtTime.Value
    'UserForm2Begin'
    .Cells(lRow, 7).Value = Me.txtKas.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 8).Value = Me.txtInvestasi.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 9).Value = Me.txtDanaTerbatas.Value
    .Cells(lRow, 10).Value = Me.txtPiutangUsaha.Value
    'UserForm2End'
  End With

'Clear input controls.
Me.txtNo.Value = ""
Me.txtKode.Value = ""
Me.txtNamaPerusahaan.Value = ""
Me.txtSector.Value = ""
Me.txtTime.Value = ""
'Userform2Begin'
Me.txtKas.Value = ""
Me.txtInvestasi.Value = ""
Me.txtDanaTerbatas.Value = ""
Me.txtPiutangUsaha.Value = ""
'Userform2End'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not use an object that holds all data that you input in the several forms and use this object to later print everything to excel?

Comment: How can i use that sir? i hope it is more simple than the above code, because I am new to excel VB, the above code, I just copied it from the internet and transform it for the use of my data. Thank you for your answer

Comment: easier it wont be, because you need to use Actionlisteners for the buttons. But it would be a cleaner way. A easy, but dirty, solution I will post you as an answer.

Comment: Okay sir, how can i do that?

Comment: Why do you not use a multipage control instead of creating more userforms. It may make it a lot easier to make the information available between the pages of this control than storing them in memory via the VBA code.

Comment: @Tom Yeah Tom, the multipage helps me out. I have tried it, thanks for the advice. Now i'm still trying for the Class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you declare every textfield that you want to read from public you can do it like this:

```
 Class MainForm
    Form firstPage
    Form secondPage
    ...

    Private Sub cmdAddData_Click()
     'Copy input values to sheet.
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Summary")
    lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    With ws
        .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = firstPage.txtNo.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = firstPage.txtKode.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = firstPage.txtNamaPerusahaan.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = firstPage.txtSector.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = firstPage.txtTime.Value
        'UserForm2Begin'
        .Cells(lRow, 7).Value = secondPage.txtKas.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 8).Value = secondPage.txtInvestasi.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 9).Value = secondPage.txtDanaTerbatas.Value
        .Cells(lRow, 10).Value = secondPage.txtPiutangUsaha.Value
        'UserForm2End'
      End With

    'Clear input controls.
    Me.txtNo.Value = ""
    Me.txtKode.Value = ""
    Me.txtNamaPerusahaan.Value = ""

    firstPage.txtSector.Value = ""
    firstPage.txtTime.Value = ""
    'Userform2Begin'
    secondPage.txtKas.Value = ""
    secondPage.txtInvestasi.Value = ""
    secondPage.txtDanaTerbatas.Value = ""
    secondPage.txtPiutangUsaha.Value = ""

End Sub



End Class
```

As mentioned if you want to use this approach, you need to set the visibility to public (in the graphical editor its the attribute `Modifiers`)

The better solution would be you declare an object in the Mainfrom that has attributes for all values you want to have in you Excel file later. Then give this object to every form, for example in the constructor, and fill it.
In you Mainform you can then read all attributes form the object and write them to the file.
The Object for holding you data would somthing like this:

```
    Class DataObject
        Public txtNo as String
        Public txtKode as String
        ...
    End Class
```

You declare it in the first Form that the user can see and then give it to every form that follows

```
Class FirstForm
   Dim data as DataObject
   ...

   private sub openNextWindow()
       dim sec as SecondForm= new SecondForm(DataObject)
       ...
   end sub
end class
```

Until you finally are at your cmdAddData where you do it like this:

```
Private Sub cmdAddData_Click()
     'Copy input values to sheet.
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Summary")
    lRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    With ws
        .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = data.txtNo
        .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = data.txtKode
        ...      
End Sub
```

Comment: The Class declared as text in my Excel VB, how can i handle that sir?

Comment: see updated Answer, if you would be fit using reflection you could even easy your code in the "With ws" part, but this is a more complex topic so I will better not use it at this place

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be creating a **Class Module** in 1st Form and accessing it in all other subsequent forms. A working example can be seen in below screenshot.

Sorry couldn't copy and paste the exact code since its just an example I've created to show how effectively we can create data entry forms using Classes in VBA.

To add a *Class Module*: Menu -> Insert -> Class Module and rename it in *Properties Window* located in the left bottom.

[image: Data Entry from User Forms in Excel]

**Happy VBA :-)**

Comment: Ah yes, this is also clear help. I just barely know the Class,i'm trying to figure this out. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If this approach helps you achieve your goal, mark the answer as accepted to help the others in the future.

Comment: I have marked previous answer . How can i mark this as accepted also , because this answer also helps me visually